# MSBuild Task to move all files or folders?

Tags: configuration, msbuild, continuous-integration, build-automation

Is there an MSBuild task that will move a file OR a folder? Core, extension, community, wherever is fine.

I have an itemgroup that specifies a list of files and folders that are to be moved.  I could split it out into two lists - one of files and one of folders.  However, I would like to work out a task that could just handle both. I have looked for a while, and can not find any advice on how to do this.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSBuild Extension Pack has a RoboCopy task which can handle your situation, see

```
MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.RoboCopy
```

See this post for additional help:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/11/07/using-robocopy-to-move-files-and-folders.aspx